# powershell finding disk raw or MBR/GPT

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am looking for AND condition in below command as I need offline and raw drives 
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-Disk | where-Object IsOffline -EQ $true;

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-disk

Number Friendly Name                            OperationalStatus                    Total Size Partition Style
------ -------------                            -----------------                    ---------- ---------------
0      AWS PVDISK SCSI Disk Device              Online                                   100 GB MBR
1      AWS PVDISK SCSI Disk Device              Offline                                  100 GB RAW
2      AWS PVDISK SCSI Disk Device              Offline                                  100 GB RAW
```

Answer (score 1):

So a few things wrong. I recommend learning the proper Powershell syntax. Here is what you want to do.

```
Get-Disk | Where partitionstyle -eq 'raw' | Out-file -FilePath C:\Users\user\Desktop\rawDisk.txt
```

Never use echo in powershell. Use `write-output` if need be. If writing to a file, the do `out-file`.

Comment: just replace the `raw` with MBR or GPT, or which ever one you want.